# Nice expression for curvature of a Kähler surface

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature, kahler-manifolds

Let $\Sigma$ be a Riemann surface with symplectic form $\omega$ and complex structure $J$, and denote by $g$ the induced metric. My question is

> Is there a nice expression of the Gaussian curvature of $g$ in terms of $\omega$ and $J$?

I have though about this problem for a while, but I haven't been able to find anything. Any solution, hint or reference would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean _Riemann surface_ (complex dimension $1$) or _Kähler surface_ (complex dimension $2$)? If it's the latter, the Gaussian curvature is not intrinsically defined.

Comment: @JackLee I was not aware of this convention. I mean a Riemann surface.

Answer (score 2):

For Riemann surfaces, the formulas are very simple. If $z=x+iy$ is a local holomorphic coordinate, the Kähler form can be written $\omega = \tfrac i 2\, h^2\, dz\wedge d{\bar z}$ for some smooth positive function $h$. The Riemannian metric is then $g= h^2\, dz\,d\bar z$ (where juxtaposition denotes the symmetric product), and the Gaussian curvature is $K = - \Delta(\log h)/h^2$, where $\Delta$ is the usual Laplace operator in $(x,y)$-coordinates.

[One source: Griffiths & Harris, *Principles of Algebraic Geometry*, Chapter 0.]

Comment: Thank you! I imagine that in the second line you mean $h$ when you write $\lambda$? Also, do you have an explicit formula just in terms of $\omega$ and $J$ (without choosing local coordinates)?

Comment: Oops, sorry. Corrected. As for a formula involving only $\omega$ and $J$, I don't know one off the top of my head.

Comment: Well, I imagine we can at least write $h^2 = \tfrac{1}{2}\tr(g)$, where we see $g_m:T_mM\otime T_mM\to\mathbb{R}$ as a matrix (bilinear form). We can also write $g = \omega J$ (looking at everything as matrices) to get something maybe.

Comment: The problem is that the trace of $g$ is coordinate-dependent.  The curvature has a simple formula in terms of the trace only if you compute it in holomorphic coordinates.